# Probability distribution of measurements

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

I am new to statistics and recently learned about ISO guidelines for [Accuracy & Precision](https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#iso:std:iso:5725:-1:en) and [Uncertainty & Error](https://www.iso.org/sites/JCGM/GUM/JCGM100/C045315e-html/C045315e.html?csnumber=50461). But there are some graphs of probability distribution I found on internet which I am not able to grasp.

[image Source, it needs atleast 10 reputation to post an image](https://images.app.goo.gl/nehM4J4TqaEmyXn97)

Q. In this graph(above in the link) if systematic error is zero then average value will be the true value! How's that possible? i.e. if we take measurements under a condition of zero systematic error , average of whatever we measured will be equal to true value but aren't there some random error in average of measurement? And why random error here is described with respect to measured value not to mean of measured value?

In first graph how can we add some details like accuracy, precision and Trueness?**Could someone post a single graph of probability distribution in which all the parameters of measurement like *Random error, Systematic error, Total error, Uncertainity, Accuracy, Precision and Trueness* are described?** It would also be fine if you upload a photo a hand-drawn graph in copy rather than a printed one.

Edit:- I have made a graph could someone check it that it is correct or not according to ISO definations of the terms used in graph? (Link of the definations are provided above in the question)

[Graph that I made](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YFpS.jpg)